# How to set the background behind another background image?

Tags: html, css

Here I want to set the white background line behind the blue triangle. How can I do this? 
Here is bootply [link](http://www.bootply.com/ovb9OK1TMC).

Comment: Can you please explain more! @shafayathossain

Comment: Link:-http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: You can see that there is a white line over the triangle. But I want to set the line behind the triangle.

Comment: Link:-https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use `z-index` property: See [demo](http://www.bootply.com/C6uSySxnjx)

> The z-index property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.

```
footer .container::before,footer .container::after {
background:#eeeeee;
height:1px;
width:100%;
z-index: -1;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Did you check [demo](http://www.bootply.com/C6uSySxnjx) link?  You will have to use `position` to work with `z-index`

Comment: I didn't try position:relative. Thanks a lot.